# Most efficient way to move an image from a C program to Java and shown on the screen?

Tags: java, c, ipc, video-capture, image-capture

**Background**

I am capturing video using the video4linux 2 spec.  It is captured using a C program in real-time.  I also have a Java frontend that can run both locally and remotely.  The remote side was easy, I just compress the images to JPEG and ship them over a mini-http server to the client that decompresses them and shows them on the screen.

When we run locally, I would like some way IPC to connect directly to that memory and access the images from Java.  Then, blit those to the screen using as little CPU power as possible.  This is a "surveillance" type system so I could have 8-16 camera feeds running at a time.

**Question**

What is the most efficient way to move the image data (YUV420P) from the v4l2 mmap buffer to my Java app to display it on the screen?  Please show code or point me to some api/specs if any are available.

**Answer**

In the interest of time, I decided to just use plain Sockets and send the data in RGB.  I was able to drastically improve performance when the Java client is running on the same machine.  I'm still sending JPEGs over the network if the client is running remotely.  Next, I'll need to find an optimized JPEG decoder.

By the way, this is not 2 clients, just my CameraStream widget reads and parses both types.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use a `Socket`, you're going to have to use JNI to hook into a more primitive IPC mechanism.

Given that you've got a memory buffer containing the video data, you may be able to use the "shared memory" APIs to get access to that memory from within your JVM.  Have a look at the man page for `shmat`.

You'll also need some sort of signal to tell the Java client that new video data is available.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about just making the "remote" interface perform acceptably for both situations.

Maintaining dual front ends (and in this case, some back end as well) will just mean twice the maintainance and twice the (potential) bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JNI you can try [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) (Java Native Access). By using it you can call you C API directly from Java without the need to write JNI code. Please consider preparing small DLL which defines all required methods like open, close webcam device and get image as byte array. Then use [JNAreator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) to prepare Java classes from this DLL. It works fantastic. I started playing with native code again after several years when I discovered this project.

You can also consider using [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) which is other Java API to native code. It is also as transparent as JNA, but much faster, and you don't need to use JNI too.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using JNI to expose the native memory.  See the JNI APIs around Direct Byte Buffers.

Once you expose your native memory like this in Java, copy the bytes from the DirectByteBuffer into Java byte[] arrays, and it should be much faster than your socket approach.